# Difference between client and server time ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a web service, built on ServiceStack.
It serves protobuf-net requests from window form users.

I would simply like to know how to automatically get the user's machine Current Time (for every sent request) for checking if exist time difference between client and server sides.
I would like to know if there is any built in option with servicestack or other options too... to get time when request was sent.

Comment: (removed protobuf-net tag - doesn't seem relevant, other than as a side detail)

Answer (score 3):

ServiceStack doesn't return any built-in Metadata with its Responses, so you'd need to add a `DateTime` property in your Request DTO, but if the purpose is to measure differences I'd look at returning `DateTime.Ticks` instead or if the client is in a different language return the milliseconds between the [Unix Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (highly compatible and available in most platforms) which you can get using the `DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMs()` extension method.